# positioning a div element relative to mouse clicked position using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have to show a div element relative to the position of mouse click. I have tried event.PageX it is working fine in chrome but unfortunately not in mozilla and internet explorer. Here is my code:

This is a element to be clicked. On click of this i have to place a div element in a position just relative to it.  There will so many elements which are having onclick='JavaScript:ShowMiniDialog(this);'  function.

```
    <a id="tab1" onclick='JavaScript:ShowMiniDialog(this);' href="#tabs-1">New Tab</a>
```

and the minidialog to be showed is a div element.

```
    <div id="tblStyleControl" >
          Hi i am near to you.                                         
    </div>
```

I am using the following code to position this div element:

```
    $('#tblStyleControl').css('left', event.pageX + 10);     
    $('#tblStyleControl').css('top', event.pageY - 80);
    $('#tblStyleControl').css('display', 'inline');
    $("#tblStyleControl").css("position", "absolute");
```

This code is absolutely working fine in Google Chrome browser. 
Please help me out in case of mozilla and internet explorer.

I am getting the following error.

```
    ReferenceError: event is not defined
    ...'#tblStyleControl').css('left', event.pageX + 10);
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better....

Comment: I am new to jsfiddle. I tried to create same scenario but couldn't complete. http://jsfiddle.net/mgRxn/14/

Comment: @C-link I have made set up in jsfiddle. jsfiddle.net/mgRxn/14 –

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found some solution to work around for mozilla and internet explorer. So i am giving that answer.

Instead of getting the mouse pointer co ordinates where its clicked, i tried getting the co ordinates of the html element, then i used some x and y values it really worked. unfortunately not in chrome. but still this can be answer for mozilla and internet explorer.

since event is working in ( which is mentioned in question ) we can use the same for chrome and for mozilla and internet explorer this can be the answer.

```
var left = $('#tab1').offset().left;
var top = $('#tab1').offset().top;
```

by this co ordinates i used positions. That was great. !!

Answer (score 0):

The `event` variable is supposed to be a parameter of jQuery click function. It will not be available in a custom `ShowMiniDialog(ctrl) { /* 'event' variable is not defined here */ }` function.
Try this..

```
<a id="tab1" href="#tabs-1">New Tab</a>
```

To get x,y position in all browsers,

```
$('a#tab1').click(function(event){ 
    // Calculate pageX/Y if missing and clientX/Y available
    if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
        var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
        event.pageX = event.clientX + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
        event.pageY = event.clientY + (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) - (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0);
    }
            $('#hdnCR').val(event.target.id);

    $('#tblStyleControl').css({
        'left': event.pageX + 10,
        'top': event.pageY - 80,
        'display': 'inline',
        "position": "absolute"
    }).show(); 
});
```

Avoid finding the element `$('#tblStyleControl')` multiple times for better performance.

See the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgRxn/16/)

Comment: I need the id of the clicked element too so i am passing 'this' in ShowMiniDialog function. But now event also is required. since it is undefined..  jsfiddle.net/mgRxn/14 –  please refer this link u might get some idea

Comment: Added the jsFiddle demo too.. Check that

Comment: This is working perfect for static elements. but for dynamic elements which are created using drag and drop functionality that click event is not firing even when the element is associated with 'popupTrigger' class.

Comment: Use [jQuery on() delegate function](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject/) for binding event to dynamically created elements

Comment: can u pls give a line of code where i can get this and event together using delegate binding

Comment: Did you try anything from seeing the link in my previous comment? 
Just replace `$('.popupTrigger').click(function(event){` with `$("body").on("click", ".popupTrigger", function(event){`

Comment: ya i have tried it was working for static elements and was not working for dynamically added elements...